# TLSv1_1 and TLSv1_2 upgrade for Indy with Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, indy, indy10

I have old Delphi XE2 programs which do not work anymore when new webpages are loaded (IdHTTP - SSL error)
I can for example load a page from [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) but no more from [www.morningstar.com](http://www.morningstar.com)

My Indy version (10.5.8) does not recognize TLSv1_1 nor TLSV1_2 and I don't find any INDY upgrade.

Does somebody know where I could find the last INDY upgrade?
Or is there a way to modify some indy units (like IdSSLOpenSSL unit) to support TLSV1_2?

Answer (score 2):

10.5.8 is very old. The current version is 10.6.2. Download links and [installation instructions](http://ww2.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.EN.aspx) are on [Indy's website](https://www.indyproject.org).

Comment: Well the files to download are very well hidden on that website ! I finally found something (?) at http://www.mjfreelancing.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=13&Itemid=16

Comment: Is this the last file (it seems to be from 2015)?

Comment: @Michel the MJF files are old, they have not been updated for the latest Indy releases or the latest IDEs in a long time. The Fulgan files were last updated a couple of months ago, but they are not the latest anymore, the sync with Indy's SVN was [recently turned off for good](https://www.indyproject.org/2019/11/28/indy-svn-retiring-long-live-github/). The absolute latest is now in [Indy's GitHub repo](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy).

Comment: I installed INDY 10.6.2.0, and replaced every occurrence of ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll in my harddisk with version 1.0.2.17 but i have still have EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError when trying a GET on some websites. Any idea where i could search ? I reduced my program to this:

Comment: procedure TForm8.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var HTTP:TIdHTTP;
    Handler:TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
HTTP:=TidHTTP.Create(nil);
Handler:=TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
with Handler.SSLOptions do
    begin
    SSLVersions := [sslvSSLV23,sslvTLSv1,sslvTLSV1_1,sslvTLSv1_2];
    end;
with HTTP do
    begin
    IOHandler := Handler;
    HandleRedirects:=true;
    end;
Memo1.Lines.Add(HTTP.Get(edit1.text));
HTTP.Free;
Handler.Free;
end;

Comment: @Michel replacing every OpenSSL DLL on your machine was a very bad idea. Just place the DLLs in your app's folder, that will suffice. Also, 1.0.2.21 (1.0.2u) is the latest that Indy currently supports. And get rid of `sslvSSLv23` from the `SSLVersions` property, it doesn't belong there.

Comment: Don't worry, I just renamed old DLL, now that everything is fine I restored the old dlls. After a second attempt (deleting all indy files and reinstall) everything works ok. Thanks for assistance.